# Does it make a difference if I put my virtual machine on a separate partition from OS?

Tags: linux, windows, mac

Given:
MacBookPro Late 2011
High Sierra MacOS
Parallels 13
SanDisk internal SSD 1 TB 2020

Does it matter if I put my virtual machine images on a separate partition from OS partition? I mean fragmentation-wise and performance-wise?

What are some pros and cons I might be missing?

Comment: Do you mean partition, or physical drive? Putting them on a separate partition has no loss or gain except to isolate for backup strategy. A separate drive entirely, there is no penalty except the relative speeds of the two drives.

Comment: I'm thinking fragmentation-wise and performance

Comment: Then it entirely depends on your drive spec & OS, SSDs just don't care about fragmentation, it doesn't exist as a concept to them. Please add details to your original question.

Comment: File fragmentation on an SSD isn't a concern.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, if someone can put this as answer I’ll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an SSD there is no gain or loss at all, so long as the drive overall has adequate free space.

An SSD doesn't suffer from fragmentation in the same way as an old spinny rust HD & partitioning does not equate to 'half the disk' in the same way. Data placement has no relationship to any particular spot on the SSD, unlike HD. On macOS with APFS, not even the size of any partition is fixed, either can expand to take up any amount of free space on the drive; the partition 'borders' are virtual & totally flexible.
The only real benefit I can see to using a separate partition would be to make backup management simpler.

Using a second drive rather than a separate partition on the same SSD would benefit from both the backup separation & physical safety of not being victim to a physical failure of the boot drive, but that could be said of any physical separation.